# Show that triangle $ABC$ is equilateral

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, quadrilateral

**Question**

On the small arc $BC$ of the circumscribed circle of the triangle $ABC$, consider two distinct points $M$ and $N$, different from the ends of the arc. We know that the relations $MB+ MC=MA$ and $NB + NC = NA$ exist. Show that triangle $ABC$ is equilateral.

*My idea*

[image]

The first thing I noticed and that I think will help us is the fact that $ACMB, ACNB, BCNM$ are inscribed quadrilaterals.

From this info, you can see that I marked some congruent angles on my drawing.

Also, I thought of the Ptolomeu Theorem which is a bit related to the sum of sides we have, but didn't get any correct answer.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Note that since both $M, N$ are arbitrary points you could move $M$ close to $B$. In the limit $M\rightarrow B$ $MB+MC=MA \rightarrow BC=BA$ ; the same is true as $N \rightarrow C$, $NB+NC=NA \rightarrow CB=CA$. Since these equations hold for all $M,N$ in  minor arc $BC$ , $BC=BA=CA$ follows.

Comment: @TedBlack The statement "if $PB + PC = PA$ for all points $P$ on arc $BC$, then $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral" is weaker than "if there exist two points $M,N$ on arc $BC$ such that $MB+MC=MA$ and $NB+NC=NA$, then $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral".

Comment: @MIsha Lavrov my point was that if you give me two points on the minor arc for which $PB+PC=PA$ then any point on the minor arc will have the same property.

Comment: That's true, but I don't see how you conclude that without first proving that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral.

Comment: If we look at all points on the circle as complex numbers on the unit circle on the complex plane then since $\overline{z}=1/z$, $|z_M-z_B|=(z_M-z_B)i e^{-i\frac{\arg z_M+\arg z_B}{2}}$. Then $|z_M-z_B|+|z_M-z_C|=|z_M-z_A|$ can be written as $(z_M-z_B)e^{-i\frac{\arg z_B}{2}}+(z_M-z_C)e^{-i\frac{\arg z_C}{2}}=(z_M-z_A)e^{-i\frac{\arg z_A}{2}}$. If we write the same eqn for $z_N$ then if we take the difference of the two equations we get $e^{-i\frac{\arg z_B}{2}}+e^{-i\frac{\arg z_C}{2}}=e^{-i\frac{\arg z_A}{2}}$ which is equivalent to $ABC$ equilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ptolemy's theorem for $ABMC$ says that $AB \cdot MC + AC \cdot MB = MA \cdot BC$. We know $MA = MB + MC$. Moving everything to one side, we get the equation $$(AB - BC) \cdot MC + (AC-BC) \cdot MB = 0.$$
If we do the same thing with $N$ in place of $M$, we get
$$(AB - BC) \cdot NC + (AC - BC) \cdot NB = 0.$$
If $AB - BC$ were nonzero, we could rearrange these to get $$\frac{MC}{MB} = \frac{BC-AC}{AB-BC} = \frac{NC}{NB}.$$
But this is impossible: if $M, N$ appear in that order on arc $BC$, then $MC > NC$ and $MB < NB$, so $\frac{MC}{MB} > \frac{NC}{NB}$.

Therefore $AB-BC=0$, which simplifies the first equation above to $(AC-BC)\cdot MB=0$, and we conclude $AC-BC = 0$ as well. In other words, $AB = BC = AC$.

---

As a side note, once we know that $AB = AC = BC = s$, Ptolemy's theorem for an arbitrary point on the circle like $M$ says that $s \cdot MC + s \cdot MB = s \cdot MA$, so $MA = MB + MC$. So for every equilateral triangle, any points $M$ and $N$ on the circle will work to construct the diagram in the problem.

Comment: I dont really understamd the part with the linearly independent eqiations. Can you explain mr without using this term. I will give bounty. THANK YOUUU

Comment: I have rephrased, but in general I was just saying that if you have two equations like $2x + 3y = 3x + 5y = 0$, then the only way for that to be true is if $x=y=0$, except in cases where one of the equations is a multiple of the other.